# Create a list from an array react.js as a FAQ

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, accordion

I'm trying to create a FAQ, I have the data coming from an API but I'm having problems on how to show it on screen, here is my data

```
0:
answer: "The wellbeing score is Empatho's way of showing an end-user what their current state of wellbeing is. "
application: "Admin Portal"
question: "What is the wellbeing score?"
section: "Wellbeing Dashboard"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
answer: "The wellbeing score is calculated using an individuals Heart Rate Variability (HRV), their passive data, as well as some survey questions that help Empatho get to know a person better. "
application: "Admin Portal"
question: "How is the wellbeing score calculated?"
section: "Wellbeing Dashboard"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

the React.js code I want to insert the data is:

```
<Accordion expanded={expanded === 'panel1'}
           onChange={handleChange('panel1')}
           sx={{ width: '100%', padding: '30px' }}
           style={{ borderRadius: 20, margin:'10px 0px' }} >

  <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                    aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
                    id="panel1bh-header"
                    sx={{ borderRadius:10 }} >
    
    <div style={{ display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center' }}>
      <div>
        <img src={wellbeingfaq} style={{ width:'auto', height:20, marginRight:25 }}/>
      </div>
      <div style={{ fontSize:'1.5em', fontWeight:'bold' }}>Wellbeing Dashboard</div>
    </div>

  </AccordionSummary>

  <AccordionDetails sx={{ padding: '20px' }}> 

    <div style={{ fontSize:'1.3em', fontWeight:'bold' }}>
      <div>Question</div>
    </div>
    <div style={{ fontSize:'1.0em'}}>
      <div>Answer</div>
    </div>                 
      
  </AccordionDetails>     
           
</Accordion>
```

I want to substitute the "Question" and "Answer"

how do I do that? I'm totally lost.

Comment: Please provide on where exactly your array of data lives. Is it in the state of the Component or in props, that way people can give you a clear answer on how to traverse through the array and render the `AccordionDetails`

Comment: Also, it seems that you need to read about how to repeat specific sections of a component when you get multiple data. You can have a read of this article https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-loop-through-arrays-in-react-3eaa8a14445

Answer (score 0):

You need to run over every item and return the JSX code that you need.
This can be done with the .map function like this:

```
<AccordionDetails> 
{ this.state.listFromApi.map((item,index) => (
 <div key={index}>
  <div>
   <div>Question</div>
   <div>{item.question}</div>
  </div

  <div style={{ fontSize:'1.0em'}}>
   <div>Answer</div>
   <div>{item.answer}</div>
  </div>
 </div>
))}
</AccordionDetails>
```

To avoid getting messy code I do recommend moving it into a function instead.

```
<AccordionDetails> 
 {this.renderQuestions()}
<AccordionDetails>
```

Comment: Please, could you me more precise, I was trying here to replicate your answer but is not working

Comment: Here is a complete version Hooks on React https://pastebin.com/HN4Ljnpy